# Database model Parent Child with single default child.

Tags: database-design, parent-child

Is there a best practice pattern to model the following parent child relationship where exactly one child can be flagged as the default child.

I can think of two ways. Which is better or is there another better alternate?

```
   - ParentTable
      - Id

   - ChildTable
      - Id
      - ParentId
      - IsDefault
```

or

```
   - ParentTable
      - Id
      - DefaultChildId

   - ChildTable
      - Id
      - ParentId
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I favor data models that prevent invalid data from existing at all.  If you use the second approach and create a foreign key relationship between DefaultChildId and the ChildTable, then you can add constraints to ensure that your database can't ever be in an invalid state -- if you try to, say, delete a child that is somebody's default child, the database will prevent you.  Using the first approach, it won't.

Specifically (as noted in a comment),  ON DELETE RESTRICT constraint should be used on DefaultChildId and ON DELETE CASCADE on ParentID.  This allows creation of records with more flexibility (you don't need to have a default child already there to be able to make a parent), prevents accidental deletion of default child without first updating to a new default, and intelligently handles deletion of the parent.

Comment: You can't use NOT NULL because it will cause chicken-or-egg problem. ON DELETE RESTRICT constraint should be used on DefaultChildId and ON DELETE CASCADE on ParentId to eventually allow deletion of parent. Please update for vote up.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking the second one is better since its easier to ensure that *one and only one* child is the default child.

The SQL is also a slightly clearer

Compare

```
SELECT * 
FROM   parenttable p 
       INNER JOIN childtable c 
         ON p.id = c.parentid 
            AND c.isdefault = 1
```

vs

```
SELECT * 
 FROM   parenttable p 
     INNER JOIN childtable c 
       ON p.defaultchildid = c.id
```